# In HttpHandler, Local System identifies image directory path, but IIS server does not identify the image directory path?

Tags: c#, image, remote-access, httphandler

I am a beginner in web application in c#. Using Asp.net Http handler, I can access image using

> http://localhost:1666/ImageHandlr.ashx?id=\\imgMachine\image1.jpg

But I could not access Image from the server

> http://localhost/ImageHandlr.ashx?id=\\imgMachine\image1.jpg

.

where ImgMachine is another Machine to provide images. Why IIS server does not access the image from the remote machine? kindly help me.  thanks

Comment: Please don't post real IP addresses in the question, especially along with such a vulnerable code.